# HTTP download with dynamic reallocation and retries

Tags: c++, error-handling, memory-management, http, winapi

This code is for downloading a file via winhttp lib, It's invoked by `StartDownload` function which tries to download n times before returning false if maximum tries exceeded. I'm worried about the dynamic realloc part in `Download` function, is my approach here have any flaws, or is there any improvements that can be made?

```
#include "HttpDownload.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Winhttp.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "winhttp.lib")

bool bResults = FALSE;
HINTERNET hSession = 0, hConnect = 0, hRequest = 0;
int RepeatedTimes = 0;

void HttpDownload::CloseHandles() {
    if (hRequest) WinHttpCloseHandle(hRequest);
    if (hConnect) WinHttpCloseHandle(hConnect);
    if (hSession) WinHttpCloseHandle(hSession);
}

bool HttpDownload::InitHttp() {
    if (!(hSession = WinHttpOpen(0, 0, 0, 0, 0))) return false;
    if (!(hConnect = WinHttpConnect(hSession, L"127.0.0.1", 80, 0))) return false;
    if (!(hRequest = WinHttpOpenRequest(hConnect, L"GET", L"/file.ext", 0, 0, 0, 0))) return false;
    if (!(bResults = WinHttpSendRequest(hRequest, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))) return false;
    if (!(bResults = WinHttpReceiveResponse(hRequest, 0))) return false;
    return true;
}

bool HttpDownload::Download() {
    if (!bResults) return false;
    unsigned long dwSize = 0;
    unsigned long dwDownloaded = 0;
    void *buf;
    bool failed = false;
    int curalloc = 8192;
    unsigned char *jar = (unsigned char*)malloc(curalloc);
    int totalDownloaded = 0;
    #define failbreak failed = true; break;
    while (1) {
        dwSize = 0;
        if (!WinHttpQueryDataAvailable(hRequest, &dwSize)) { failbreak }
        if (dwSize == 0) break;
        buf = VirtualAlloc(0, dwSize, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
        if (!buf) { failbreak }
        else {
            if (!WinHttpReadData(hRequest, buf, dwSize, &dwDownloaded)) { failbreak }
            else {
                realloc:
                if ((totalDownloaded + dwDownloaded) > curalloc) {
                    unsigned char *m = (unsigned char*)malloc(curalloc * 2);
                    curalloc = curalloc * 2;
                    memcpy(m, jar, totalDownloaded);
                    free(jar);
                    jar = m;
                    goto realloc;
                }
                memcpy((jar + totalDownloaded), buf, dwDownloaded);
                totalDownloaded += dwDownloaded;
            }
            VirtualFree(buf, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
        }
    } if (failed) return false;
    CloseHandles();
    FinalResult = (unsigned char*)malloc(totalDownloaded);
    memcpy(FinalResult, jar, totalDownloaded);
    free(jar);
    FinalDownloadedSize = totalDownloaded;
    return true;
}

bool HttpDownload::StartDownload() {
    CloseHandles();
    if (RepeatedTimes > 4) { return false; }
    RepeatedTimes++;
    bool r = InitHttp();
    if (!r) StartDownload();
    r = Download();
    if (!r) StartDownload();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: BTW this is clearly not [tag:c]; I've guessed it involves [tag:winapi], but if I've got that wrong, you'll need to add the correct tag (certainly none of those headers are standard C++, so well out of my domain!).

Comment: `HttpDownload::Download()` just awful.  absolute worst. all code is wrong from begin to end

Comment: @RbMm That is just an awful review, you should specify what's wrong about the code not just throwing random opinions, and from the way i see it the code couldn't be better it's just the dynamic reallocation i'm worried about.

Comment: in code wrong absolute all. code can not be more worst faster

Answer (score 3):

at first `StartDownload` use recursion, when it absolute not need here. enough simply loop like -

```
ULONG nTry = 4, dwError;
do {
    dwError = Download();
} while(dwError && --Try);
```

next - you not need recreate **all** handles - `hSession`, `hConnect`, `hRequest` on send request fail, but only `hRequest`. the `hSession` we usual must open only once. the `hConnect` - once per url. note that `WinHttpConnect` really not connect to server. it simply remember server url and port in internal structures. if `WinHttpOpen` or `WinHttpConnect` - no sense try call it again (this is offline calls)

so code for **synchronous** (*which is bad*) processing must look like:

```
void test()
{
    if (HINTERNET hSession = WinHttpOpen( 0,  
        WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_NO_PROXY,
        WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_NAME, 
        WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_BYPASS, 0))
    {
        if (HINTERNET hConnect = WinHttpConnect(hSession, L"stackoverflow.com", INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTPS_PORT, 0))
        {
            int nTry = 4;
            ULONG dwError;
            do 
            {
                if (HINTERNET hRequest = WinHttpOpenRequest(hConnect, L"GET", NULL,
                    NULL, WINHTTP_NO_REFERER, 
                    WINHTTP_DEFAULT_ACCEPT_TYPES, 
                    WINHTTP_FLAG_REFRESH|WINHTTP_FLAG_SECURE))
                {
                    if (WinHttpSendRequest(hRequest,
                        WINHTTP_NO_ADDITIONAL_HEADERS,
                        0, WINHTTP_NO_REQUEST_DATA, 0, 
                        0, 0) && WinHttpReceiveResponse(hRequest, 0))
                    {
                        dwError = Download(hRequest);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dwError = GetLastError();
                    }

                    WinHttpCloseHandle(hRequest);
                }
                else
                {
                    dwError = GetLastError();
                }

            } while (dwError && --nTry);

            WinHttpCloseHandle(hConnect);
        }

        WinHttpCloseHandle(hSession);
    }
}
```

now look for you `Download` implementation - it contains mistakes and amazing not effective.

```
VirtualAlloc(0, dwSize, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
```

you always, **unconditionally** allocate temporary memory buffer (`buf`), even if you main buffer `jar` containing enough free space. than reallocate `jar` if need and copy temporary buffer to it `memcpy((jar + totalDownloaded), buf, dwDownloaded);`

also note that you have potential memory leak here - `WinHttpReadData` fail - you just break loop, without free temporary `buf`.

really we not need allocate any temporary buffer. we need just read data to main buffer `jar` - `WinHttpReadData(hRequest, (PBYTE)jar + totalDownloaded, dwSize, &dwSize)`. if `jar` not have enough free space - we need reallocate it **before** `WinHttpReadData` call.

now look how you reallocate `jar` - it's just inexplicable for me

`realloc: ** goto realloc;`

for what this loop ?!? why need `curalloc = curalloc * 2;` and multiple time allocate, copy, free data ?!?. when we can just set

`curalloc = totalDownloaded + dwDownloaded;`

more better of course allocate some more memory than `totalDownloaded + dwDownloaded`. so code for `Download` can look like:

```
ULONG Download(HINTERNET hRequest)
{
    ULONG curalloc = 0x10000, dwSize, totalDownloaded = 0, cbNeed;

    HANDLE hHeap = GetProcessHeap();

    ULONG dwError = NOERROR;

    if (PVOID jar = HeapAlloc(hHeap, 0, curalloc))
    {
        do 
        {
            if (!WinHttpQueryDataAvailable(hRequest, &dwSize))
            {
                dwError = GetLastError();
                break;
            }

            cbNeed = totalDownloaded + dwSize;

            if (cbNeed > curalloc)
            {
                cbNeed = (cbNeed + 0xffff) & ~0xffff;// round to 64kb

                if (PVOID buf = HeapReAlloc(hHeap, 0, jar, cbNeed))
                {
                    curalloc = cbNeed, jar = buf;
                }
                else
                {
                    dwSize = ERROR_OUTOFMEMORY;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!WinHttpReadData(hRequest, (PBYTE)jar + totalDownloaded, dwSize, &dwSize))
            {
                dwError = GetLastError();
                break;
            }

            totalDownloaded += dwSize;

        } while (dwSize);

        if (!dwError)
        {
            DbgPrint("download %u Ok\n", totalDownloaded);
        }

        HeapFree(hHeap, 0, jar);
    }

    return GetLastError();
}
```

this is already ok, but not best. windows let reserve memory space. so good solution - at begin reserve large enough memory space (in 32bit we can reserve how minimum n*10Mb, in 64bit - gigabytes). and then allocate memory from this reserved range. with this we not need reallocate and copy data. class for this dynamic allocation:

```
class DynamicBuffer
{
    PBYTE _BaseAddress;
    SIZE_T _dwReserve, _dwSize, _dwCommit;

    static SIZE_T RoundSize(SIZE_T size)
    {
        static SIZE_T s_dwAllocationGranularity;

        if (!s_dwAllocationGranularity)
        {
            SYSTEM_INFO si;
            GetSystemInfo(&si);
            s_dwAllocationGranularity = si.dwAllocationGranularity - 1;
        }

        return (size + s_dwAllocationGranularity) & ~s_dwAllocationGranularity;
    }

public:

    DynamicBuffer()
    {
        _BaseAddress = 0, _dwReserve = 0, _dwSize = 0, _dwCommit = 0;
    }

    ~DynamicBuffer()
    {
        Reset();
    }

    ULONG Create(SIZE_T dwSize)
    {
        if (_BaseAddress = (PBYTE)VirtualAlloc(0, dwSize = RoundSize(dwSize), MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE))
        {
            _dwReserve = dwSize;
            return NOERROR;
        }

        return GetLastError();
    }

    ULONG AllocBuffer(PVOID* ppv, SIZE_T cb)
    {
        if (_dwReserve - _dwSize < cb)
        {
            return ERROR_OUTOFMEMORY;
        }

        SIZE_T dwSize = _dwSize + cb;

        if (dwSize > _dwCommit)
        {
            SIZE_T dwCommit = RoundSize(dwSize);

            if (!VirtualAlloc(_BaseAddress + _dwCommit, dwCommit - _dwCommit, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE))
            {
                return GetLastError();
            }

            _dwCommit = dwCommit;
        }

        *ppv = _BaseAddress + _dwSize;

        return NOERROR;
    }

    void AddData(SIZE_T cb)
    {
        _dwSize += cb;

        if (_dwSize > _dwCommit)
        {
            __debugbreak();
        }
    }

    PVOID getData()
    {
        return _BaseAddress;
    }

    SIZE_T getDataSize()
    {
        return _dwSize;
    }

    SIZE_T getFreeSpace()
    {
        return _dwReserve - _dwSize;
    }

    void Reset()
    {
        if (_BaseAddress)
        {
            VirtualFree(_BaseAddress, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
            _BaseAddress = 0;
        }
        _dwReserve = 0, _dwSize = 0, _dwCommit = 0;
    }
};
```

with this we can rewrite `Download` :

```
ULONG Download(HINTERNET hRequest)
{
    DynamicBuffer buf;

    ULONG dwError = NOERROR;

    if (dwError = buf.Create(0x4000000)) // 64Mb reserve
    {
        return dwError;
    }

    ULONG dwSize;

    do 
    {
        if (!WinHttpQueryDataAvailable(hRequest, &dwSize))
        {
            dwError = GetLastError();
            break;
        }

        PVOID pv;
        if (dwError = buf.AllocBuffer(&pv, dwSize))
        {
            break;
        }

        if (!WinHttpReadData(hRequest, pv, dwSize, &dwSize))
        {
            dwError = GetLastError();
            break;
        }

        buf.AddData(dwSize);

    } while (dwSize);

    if (!dwError)
    {
        DbgPrint("download %u Ok\n", buf.getDataSize());
    }

    return GetLastError();
}
```

but however always much better do **asynchronous** download. this can be done say in next way:

```
class __declspec(novtable) InternetHandle
{
    HINTERNET _hInternet;
    LONG _dwRef;

protected:

    virtual ~InternetHandle()
    {
        if (_hInternet)
        {
            WinHttpCloseHandle(_hInternet);
        }
        DbgPrint("%s<%p>\n", __FUNCTION__, this);
    }

    InternetHandle()
    {
        _dwRef = 1;
        _hInternet = 0;
        DbgPrint("%s<%p>\n", __FUNCTION__, this);
    }

public:

    void AddRef()
    {
        InterlockedIncrement(&_dwRef);
    }

    void Release()
    {
        if (!InterlockedDecrement(&_dwRef)) delete this;
    }

    HINTERNET get_handle() { return _hInternet; }

    HINTERNET set_handle(HINTERNET hInternet) { 
        return InterlockedExchangePointer(&_hInternet, hInternet);
    }
};

class CSession : public InternetHandle
{
public:
    ULONG Open(LPCWSTR pszAgentW = 0)
    {
        if (HINTERNET hSession = WinHttpOpen( pszAgentW,  
            WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_NO_PROXY,
            WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_NAME, 
            WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_BYPASS, WINHTTP_FLAG_ASYNC))
        {
            set_handle(hSession);

            return NOERROR;
        }

        return GetLastError();
    }
};

class CTarget : public InternetHandle
{
    CSession* _pSession;

    virtual ~CTarget()
    {
        _pSession->Release();
    }
public:

    ULONG Set(PCWSTR pswzServerName, INTERNET_PORT nServerPort)
    {
        if (HINTERNET hConnect = WinHttpConnect(_pSession->get_handle(), pswzServerName, nServerPort, 0))
        {
            set_handle(hConnect);
            return NOERROR;
        }

        return GetLastError();
    }

    CTarget(CSession* pSession) : _pSession(pSession)
    {
        pSession->AddRef();
    }
};

class DownloadCtx : public InternetHandle, public DynamicBuffer, public WINHTTP_ASYNC_RESULT
{
    CTarget* _pTarget;
    ULONG _nTryCount;
    ULONG _dwThreadId;

    virtual ~DownloadCtx()
    {
        DbgPrint("<%u,%u> %u\n", dwResult, dwError, getDataSize());

        _pTarget->Release();

        PostThreadMessage(_dwThreadId, WM_QUIT, dwResult, dwError);
    }

public:
    DownloadCtx(CTarget* pTarget, ULONG nTryCount) : _pTarget(pTarget), _nTryCount(nTryCount)
    {
        pTarget->AddRef();
        dwError = ERROR_IO_PENDING, dwResult = 0;
        _dwThreadId = GetCurrentThreadId();
    }

    ULONG SendRequest()
    {
        if (get_handle()) __debugbreak();

        if (!dwError)
        {
            return NOERROR;
        }

        if (!_nTryCount--)
        {
            return dwError;
        }

        dwError = ERROR_IO_PENDING, dwResult = 0;

        Reset();

        DbgPrint("=========== %x ============\n", _nTryCount);

        if (HINTERNET hRequest = WinHttpOpenRequest(_pTarget->get_handle(), L"GET", NULL,
            NULL, WINHTTP_NO_REFERER, 
            WINHTTP_DEFAULT_ACCEPT_TYPES, 
            WINHTTP_FLAG_REFRESH|WINHTTP_FLAG_SECURE))
        {
            PVOID Context = this;

            if (WinHttpSetOption(hRequest, WINHTTP_OPTION_CONTEXT_VALUE, &Context, sizeof(Context)))
            {
                AddRef();

                set_handle(hRequest);

                WinHttpSetStatusCallback(
                    hRequest,
                    _StatusCallback,
                    WINHTTP_CALLBACK_FLAG_ALL_NOTIFICATIONS,
                    NULL );

                if (!WinHttpSendRequest(hRequest,
                    WINHTTP_NO_ADDITIONAL_HEADERS,
                    0, WINHTTP_NO_REQUEST_DATA, 0, 
                    0, (DWORD_PTR)this))
                {
                    Close(GetLastError(), API_SEND_REQUEST);
                }

                return NOERROR;
            }

            WinHttpCloseHandle(hRequest);
        }

        return GetLastError();
    }

    ULONG Read(HINTERNET hRequest)
    {
        if (DWORD dwNumberOfBytesToRead = (DWORD)min(0x10000, getFreeSpace()))
        {
            PVOID Buf;
            if (ULONG err = AllocBuffer(&Buf, dwNumberOfBytesToRead))
            {
                return err;
            }

            DbgPrint("Begin Read %u\n", dwNumberOfBytesToRead);

            return WinHttpReadData(hRequest, Buf, 0x10000, 0) ? NOERROR : GetLastError();
        }

        return ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW;
    }

    void Close(ULONG err, DWORD_PTR from)
    {
        if (HINTERNET hRequest = set_handle(0))
        {
            dwError = err, dwResult = from;
            WinHttpCloseHandle(hRequest);
        }
    }

    static void CALLBACK _StatusCallback(
        __in  HINTERNET hRequest,
        __in  DWORD_PTR Context,
        __in  DWORD dwInternetStatus,
        __in  LPVOID lpvStatusInformation,
        __in  DWORD dwStatusInformationLength
        )
    {
        reinterpret_cast<DownloadCtx*>(Context)->StatusCallback(
            hRequest, dwInternetStatus, lpvStatusInformation, dwStatusInformationLength);
    }

    void StatusCallback(
        __in  HINTERNET hRequest,
        __in  DWORD dwInternetStatus,
        __in  LPVOID lpvStatusInformation,
        __in  DWORD dwStatusInformationLength
        );
};

void DownloadCtx::StatusCallback(
                                      __in  HINTERNET hRequest,
                                      __in  DWORD dwInternetStatus,
                                      __in  LPVOID lpvStatusInformation,
                                      __in  DWORD dwStatusInformationLength
                                      )
{
    DbgPrint("%x>%p %08x %p %x\n", GetCurrentThreadId(), hRequest,
        dwInternetStatus, lpvStatusInformation, dwStatusInformationLength);

    ULONG Error;
    DWORD_PTR Result;

    switch (dwInternetStatus)
    {
    default: return;

    case WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_HANDLE_CLOSING:
        SendRequest();
        Release();
        return;

    case WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_REQUEST_ERROR:
        Error = reinterpret_cast<WINHTTP_ASYNC_RESULT*>(lpvStatusInformation)->dwError;
        Result = reinterpret_cast<WINHTTP_ASYNC_RESULT*>(lpvStatusInformation)->dwResult;
        break;

    case WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_SENDREQUEST_COMPLETE:
        if (WinHttpReceiveResponse(hRequest, NULL))
        {
            return;
        }

        Error = GetLastError(), Result = API_RECEIVE_RESPONSE;
        break;

    case WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_READ_COMPLETE:

        DbgPrint("READ_COMPLETE:%u\n",dwStatusInformationLength);

        if (dwStatusInformationLength)
        {
            AddData(dwStatusInformationLength);

            if (Error = Read(hRequest))
            {
                Result = API_READ_DATA;
                break;
            }
            return ;
        }

        Error = NOERROR, Result = 0;
        break;

    case WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_HEADERS_AVAILABLE:

        static volatile UCHAR guz;
        union {
            PWSTR sz;
            PVOID buf;
        };
        PVOID stack = _alloca(guz);
        ULONG cb = 0, rcb = 32;
        do 
        {
            if (cb < rcb)
            {
                rcb = cb = (ULONG)((PBYTE)stack - (PBYTE)(buf = _alloca(rcb - cb)));
            }

            if (WinHttpQueryHeaders(hRequest, WINHTTP_QUERY_CONTENT_LENGTH, 0, buf, &rcb, 0))
            {
                Error = NOERROR;

                if (cb = wcstoul(sz, &sz, 10))
                {
                    DbgPrint("Content-Length: %u\n", cb);
                    cb++;
                }
                else
                {
                    Error = ERROR_NO_DATA;
                }
                break;
            }
        } while ((Error = GetLastError()) == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER);

        Result = 0;

        switch (Error)
        {
        case ERROR_WINHTTP_HEADER_NOT_FOUND:
            cb = 0x4000000;// 64 mb reserve
        case NOERROR:
            if (Error = Create(cb))
            {
                break;
            }

            if (Error = Read(hRequest))
            {
                Result = API_READ_DATA;
                break;
            }

            return ;
        }
        break;
    }

    Close(Error, Result);
}

void winhttp()
{
    if (CSession* pSession = new CSession)
    {
        if (!pSession->Open())
        {
            if (CTarget* pTarget = new CTarget(pSession))
            {
                if (!pTarget->Set(L"stackoverflow.com", INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTPS_PORT))
                {
                    if (DownloadCtx* Ctx = new DownloadCtx(pTarget, 4))
                    {
                        Ctx->SendRequest();

                        Ctx->Release();
                    }
                }
                pTarget->Release();
            }
        }

        pSession->Release();
    }

    MessageBoxW(0,0,L"for demo",0);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use WinInet for download?

Comment: @BarmakShemirani - no, code will be very near - [Porting WinINet Applications to WinHTTP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384068(v=vs.85).aspx)